# Using a Sass variable mapped to an hsl value doesn't work when trying to use it with hsla

Tags: css, colors, sass, hsl

I have a Sass variable which mapped to an hsl value. When I try to use it with hsla to add a little transparency, doesn't work. I'm doing this:

```
$white:hsl(100, 100%, 100%);

.thing{
 color:hsla($white,.9);
}
```

Using gulp-sass to build my CSS, I get this error: "required parameter $lightness is missing in call to function hsla on line {line number} in {file's path}"

If I replace the `hsla` with `rgba` it works fine and, yes, I can do that, but I'd like to keep all my colors in hsl. Is there a workaround or is this a Sass issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an issue with SASS, the functionality simply doesn't exist. If you look at the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html), there are two versions of rgba(), one that accepts all of the parameters separately and one that accepts a [Color](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/Color.html) object.

[`rgba($red, $green, $blue, $alpha)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgba-instance_method)
[`rgba($color, $alpha)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgba-instance_method)

If you look at the documentation for hsla(), it only accepts the values separately.

[`hsla($hue, $saturation, $lightness, $alpha)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#hsla-instance_method)

To achieve your goal, you could do this:

```
$white:hsl(100, 100%, 100%);

.thing{
 color: hsla(hue($white), saturation($white), lightness($white), .9);
}
```

Or... if you want to pass the Color object, you can create your own function since you [can't overload functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687817/is-it-possible-to-overload-mixins-in-sass); e.g. `hslac($color, $alpha)`

```
@function hslac($color, $alpha) {
  @if(type-of($color) == "color") {
    @return hsla(hue($color), saturation($color), lightness($color), $alpha);
  }
  @else {
    @error "You didn't pass a color object";
  }
}
```